# Ruby unable to send SSL request but Curl Can

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, ssl

I got the error in Ruby. But  it works in `CURL`.

Environment is `rbenv`

Ruby version : `ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]`

```
error: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

### Curl

```
curl -k https://xx:443/ -i \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-X POST -d @${1} https://xx:443/service/
```

### Ruby

```
@uri = URI.parse(server_url)
@https = Net::HTTP.new(@uri.host, @uri.port)
@https.use_ssl = true

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(@uri.path, initheader = @header )
to_send_body = {
  "ServiceID" => "SignUp",
  "UserID" => "fs.test@dsd.com",
  "Password" => "123456789"
}
req.body = to_send_body.to_json
res = @https.request(req)
```

### data.json

```
{"ServiceID" : "SignUp","UserID" : "poc.test@123.com","Password" : "123456789"}
```

### UPDATE

I finished it by curb gem finally, but still failed on http way,

### curb version

```
c = Curl::Easy.http_post("https://1xx.xx.x.2:443/service/", to_send_body.to_json   
    ) do |curl|
      curl.ssl_verify_peer = false
      curl.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
      curl.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-k` flag in curl means that it will still connect when the cert is invalid. To accomplish the same thing in ruby, use the following

```
@https = Net::HTTP.new(@uri.host, @uri.port)
@https.use_ssl = true
@https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Comment: How could I send the json file content in Ruby? In Curl, I only need to specify the json file path. thanks

Comment: try `req.body = to_send_body.to_json`